# How to solve problem in GFCI circuit where three-prong tester shows correct wiring, but drawing power on downstream outlet causes a circuit break?

Tags: receptacle, gfci

The circuit has 3 outlets; the first in line is a GFCI outlet. All outlets show correct wiring with the two lights illuminated on a three prong tester. Powered device works in the GFCI outlet, but the same device causes a circuit break in the two other outlets when turned on. I've problem-solved everywhere I know including testing to verify the correct line wire connected to the line terminal.  Thank you for any help.

Comment: What kind of "circuit break"? The GFCI or the actual circuit breaker in the panel?

Comment: Please rovide pictures, and do please clarify if the downstream outlets are causing a GFCI trip or a Circuit Breaker trip. If a GFCI trip it's nearly aways some intersection of not using the right terminals even though you claim to have checked, or neutral and ground being connected where they should not be.

Comment: Are the downstream outlets supposed to be GFCI protected or not? i.e. how is the on-going wiring connected in the GFCI's box?

Comment: It was a GFCI trip. I did figure out the problem. It doesn't work to add a GFCI to a shared neutral circuit. In hind sight, ...... of course.  Thank you for the offers for help.